# Change html table row color which has an style applied

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple table with a style applied.

What I need is change a row color of the table.

It works fine if the table has no style applied, but as soon as there is a style, I can't change the row color anymore.

Tried to change the color with applying a new class or directly (even tried with !important) and with or without jQuery.

```js
$(document).ready(readyToGo);

function readyToGo(jQuery) {
  $('input').prop('disabled', false);
}

function displayData(jsonData) {
  var posta;
  for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
    posta = jsonData[i][2];

    $('#myTable').append("<tr><td>" + jsonData[i][0] + "</td><td>" + jsonData[i][1] + "</td><td>" + posta + "</td><td>" + jsonData[i][3] + "</td><td>" + jsonData[i][4] + "</td></tr>")
  }

  document.getElementById("myTable").rows[1].className = "red";
  //document.getElementById("myTable").rows[1].style.backgroundColor = "red";     
  //$('#myTable tr:eq(1)').css('background-color', '#f00');
}

function parseData(files) {
  var selectedFile = files[0];

  Papa.parse(selectedFile, {
    complete: function(results) {
      displayData(results.data);
    }
  })

}
```

```css
table.gridtable {
  font-family: verdana, arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #333333;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #666666;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table.gridtable th {
  border-width: 1px;
  padding: 8px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #666666;
  background-color: #dedede;
}
table.gridtable td {
  border-width: 1px;
  padding: 8px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #666666;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.red {
  background-color: #ff0000 !important;
}
```

```html
<!--script src="/Posta/javascript/papaparse.js"></script>
<script src="/Posta/javascript/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="/Posta/MainServlet">

  CSV datoteka&nbsp;
  <input type="file" id="input" onchange="parseData(this.files)" disabled/>
</form>
<hr>
<table id="myTable" class="gridtable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Ime</th>
      <th>Prezime</th>
      <th>PBR</th>
      <th>Grad</th>
      <th>Telefon</th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: css isn't just about where a rule is, it's about rule specificity too. `table.gridtable td` is far more 'specific' than `.red`, so the more specific rule wins.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
table.gridtable tr.red td {
    background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

Or

```
.red, table.gridtable tr.red td {
    background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

Also I can't confirm that your JS is going to work and since you're already (in your example) loading jQuery here's a snippit that might help you out.

```
$("#myTable tr:eq( 0 )").addClass("red");
//where 0 is the first row.
```

[Here's my jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k5870e8f/)

With CSS the rule is that the most specific rule wins. So when you had your `table.gridtable td` defining the background color of the row that rule was going to win. I'm not sure why !important wasn't working in your example code but I would suggest staying away from the !important tag unless it is absolutely necessary.

In my answer I applied the .red class to the `table.gridtable tr.red td` so that is is more specific than the `table.gridtable td`. This should result in the selected tr having a red background color. Additionally with my second example, I preserved the .red class in case you wanted to use it elsewhere while keeping the same rules applied.

Comment: Unfortunately, it still does not work. Do I have to change the line for coloring: document.getElementById("myTable").rows[1].className = "red"; ? And way does this not work: document.getElementById("myTable").rows[1].style.backgroundColor = "red"; Should that not override the css?

Comment: Ah yes, I'm styling the row to have the background color of red, you're styling the td to have the background color of grey. I'll update my code to better answer your question.

Comment: Thank you. The document.getElementById("myTable").rows[1].className = "red" now works but the jQuery version (addClass) is not.

Comment: Only thing I can think of as to why the jquery wouldn't be working is that jquery might be in non conflict mode and need to be referenced with `jQuery("selector")` instead of `$("selector")`.